# I need check if an input is empty in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Why this verifying dont work?I need that when the button is clicked, you need to check if the input is empty.

controller:

```
$scope.closeCart = function(){
    if(!$scope.name){
        $scope.modal.hide();
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items);
    }
    else{
             $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: "Coloque um nome de identificação para retirada do produto!",
                okText: "Confirmar",
                okType: "button-dark"
            });
    }
};
```

html:

```
<label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Name:</span>
        <input ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="your name">
    </label>
<button class="button button-large button-full button-assertive" ng-click="closeCart()">Pagar</button>
```

Comment: Maybe your input isn`t empty, because there are some spaces or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you dont use form validation?

```
<form name="myForm">
    <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Name:</span>
            <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text" placeholder="your name" required>

        </label>
     <label ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid"> your error message</label>
    <button class="button button-large button-full button-assertive" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="closeCart()">Pagar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, but i like to know why the way i'm doing dont work :/

Comment: @FelipeCustodio Then you must post your whole code. Because nothing seems to be wrong... Best way is to make a plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: if I need to do something like that again i will, but for now i think the form validation is a very good option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling the wrong function on the ng-click event:

```
wrong: ng-click="fecharPedido()"
correct: ng-click="closeCart()"
```

Best,
Fabian

Comment: sorry I forgot to translate this part

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `var alertPopup` but never calling it.  You can try either removing `var alertPopup =` or adding `alertPopup();` at the end of your `else` block.

As a side note, `$ionicPopup` uses promises, so you can follow your `alertPopup` with a `.then` block to perform additional processing after the popup closes.

You can find more details [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/).

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue, or are you still having trouble with it?

Comment: Still not getting into if

Comment: How are you testing this?  Are you using `ionic serve` or are you testing on a device/emulator?

Comment: i'm using ionic lab to teste